# Json type not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Why can't I return Json. It is underlined and does not exist in the current context.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Results;
using System.Web.Mvc;

//class and namespace detail removed to keep this post short

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string url, StringContent data, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                //the line below is the error******** 
                return Json(new { HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK });
        }
    }
```

I also tried `install-package System.Json` and this didn't help.

I'm aware there are probably other things wrong, the code has never worked as I started it an hour ago but I can't understand why `Json` is not recognized

This is from within a class library (if it matters)

Comment: The method is defined outside any class or namespace!?

Comment: @PeterBons, I'm sorry. No, I just removed that to keep the post short. Updated to make it clear. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method is a helper method of Web API's `ApiController` and should be called within a `ApiController` derived class.

```
public class MyApiController : System.Web.Http.ApiController {

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string url, StringContent data, Dictionary<string, string> headers) {
        using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Json(new { HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK });
        }
    }    
}
```

The same exists for MVC `Controller` derived classes as well

```
public class MyController : Controller {

    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(string url, StringContent data, Dictionary<string, string> headers) {
        using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Json(new { HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Ah, and I guess I could return Content if I inherit from Controller then?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions `Controller` has a `Json` helper method as well. You should probably update your question to clarify exactly what you are doing. The assumption was web API because of the types used in your example.